# Anova reject null hypothesis but T-test accept null hypothesis

Tags: anova, t-test

I tested my data using anova and the result is reject the null hypothesis, meaning that there are significance in my data. So, I tested the same data again using T-test but it then the result said that the null hypothesis is accepted. My data has 3 column (a, b and c). Is it logic for the result to show like that? anova rejected null hypothesis and t test accepted the null hypothesis? If it is logic, how should i conclude the result? I'm using 90% confidence interval.

For anova test :
F stats = 28126.8
P-value = 0
F crit = 1.42693

For T-test :

a vs b
t stat = 0.44965721
P two tail = 0.964191412
t crit two tail = 1.654554875

a vs c
t stat = -0.508842709
P two tail = 0.611586028
t crit two tail = 1.654743774

b vs c 
t stat = -0.552393274
P two tail = 0.581474613
t crit two tail = 1.654743774

Comment: This is a stats question, not a programming one. I'd recommend checking here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No worries! FWIW, you should reference this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148633/anova-not-significant-but-t-test-significant